# Live changes Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, npm-live-server

I'm looking for something like *npm live-server*, that refreshes my webbrowser every time I make changes to a document. Npm live-server doesn't work with PHP files.

Currently using XAMPP Apache/MySQL to run WP locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use GULP with browser-sync

Comment: Can't get it working using XAMPP...

Comment: First you need to configure gulp file in your theme folder. Then run the gulp file. Show your full gulp configured file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the one's that are interested: here is the final solution.
(Big thanks to [@Kintamasis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5939878/kintamasis) )

1. Install Gulp / [Gulp BrowserSync](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp)
2. Create a `gulpfile.js` in your themes' folder.

```
    var gulp        = require('gulp');
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
    
    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
        browserSync.init({
            proxy: "YOUR PROXY HERE"
        });
    
        gulp.watch("*").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    });
```

3. Run `gulp browser-sync` in your WP theme folder.